# First name misspelled on South Africa visa

Tags: visas, south-africa

My name was written as Adedejo instead of Adedeji on my South Africa visa. What do I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried notifying the South African consulate of this error?

Comment: @phoog I think that’s the answer :-)